# PySide. Rendering lines. Moving objects in QGraphisView

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I am trying to launch this code.
https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/plain/examples/widgets/graphicsview/anchorlayout/anchorlayout.py

And I can see the lines when I move the window inside the QGraphicView area.

What may be the reason for a such situation?

[image: Example of bad lines]

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10. 20H2. 1904.906

Comment: I don't notice this using PySide 6.0.3 (also on Windows 10 20H2).